# An unexpected sorting of const map

Tags: c++

I have declared a const map of some keys and values. The keys on the map were declared in a disordered manner.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

int main(){

    const std::map<std::string, int> ROMES = {                                                                
        { "I", 1 },
        { "V", 5 },
        { "X", 10 },
        { "L" , 50},
        { "C", 100 },
        { "D", 500 },
        { "M", 1000 }
    };

    for( auto const& [key, val] : ROMES ){
        std::cout << key         
          << ':'  
          << std::to_string(val)        
          << std::endl ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The content of the map has been printed on the console. I was surprised that the map elements were sorted out in alphabetical order.

```
C:100
D:500
I:1
L:50
M:1000
V:5
X:10
```

Why did this happen? And when?

Comment: Note: neither of the `std::*map` classes will preserve order. If you need that, use `std::vector<std::pair<>>`

Comment: They don't preserve _insertion_ order. They do preserve _comparison_ order.

Comment: While I want to +1 this for being well written, doing _any_ research on "std map" yield instantly that it's a sorted container

Comment: *I was surprised that the map elements were sorted*  Why is it a surprise?  It is clearly stated in all the docs I have read that`std::map` sorts the keys.  Unless you expected a Java-style linked hash map, this should not be a surprise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [standard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) says:

> Internally, the elements in a map are always sorted by its key following a specific strict weak ordering criterion indicated by its internal comparison object (of type Compare).

So, elements are sorted automatically as you insert them to the map.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` sorts elements by comparing their keys. By default, it uses `std::less` for the comparison, and [`std::string` implements `operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) to compare strings lexographically. That is why you see your elements being sorted in alphabetical order.

For what you want, you can give `std::map` a custom comparator to compare the keys based on the numerical values that they represent, instead of comparing them literally.

Otherwise, use `std::unordered_map` instead, or even just `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>` like @Yksisarvinen suggested in comments.

Comment: Im curious why this has 2 downvotes. Edit : It may be that OP wants to maintain the order of insertion and not necessarily want them to be sorted at all.